# RAGE on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

I installed steam (windows version through wine), and installed Black Ops II but whenever it opened, it gave me an error. Is there anyway to get it to run (I also would like to play RAGE)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

SO black ops 2 wont work, but RAGE Installed but I get this error.

```
Rage.1700.342015 win-x86 Release  Oct 10 2012 14:14:10
------ Initializing File System ------
Current search path:
C:/users/peter/Saved Games/id Software/Rage/base/
C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/RAGE/base/
file system initialized.
BenchmarkGameData: ofs 0 and 0x1208090624x 
20904 microseconds
15923 microseconds
9822 microseconds
10490 microseconds
9141 microseconds
9830 microseconds
9817 microseconds
9781 microseconds
9836 microseconds
9389 microseconds
Average seek time without outliers: 10611 microseconds

fileBenchmarkImpliesGameIsOnHD: true
---------------------------
1 CPU package, 2 physical cores, 2 logical cores
3800 MHz AMD CPU with MMX & SSE & SSE2 & SSE3 & SSSE3 & SSE41 & SSE42 & AVX
16384 kB 1st level cache, 1048576 kB 2nd level cache, 0 kB 3rd level cache
3136 MB System Memory
Winsock Initialized
Found interface: enp1s0 enp1s0 - 0.0.0.0 NULL netmask - skipped
Found interface: wlx801f02a2d994 wlx801f02a2d994 - 192.168.10.166/255.255.255.0
Sys_InitNetworking: adding loopback interface
execing default.cfg
execing joystick.cfg
execing default.cfg
execing joystick.cfg
execing default.cfg
execing joystick.cfg
execing default.cfg
execing joystick.cfg
ReadTitleStorage: MANUALLY CREATED
Num args: 32
chainRally_weighting = 0.40
meteorRally_weighting = 0.25
Carnage_weighting = 0.20
triadRally_weighting = 0.15
gearhead_weighting = 0.19
meteor_weighting = 0.19
reactor_weighting = 0.19
southernHighway_weighting = 0.19
abandoned_weighting = 0.19
prime_weighting = 0.05
meteor_Shower_killScore = 1
vdm_killScore = 10
rally_killScore = 1
tri_rally_killScore = 5
rallyPointScore = 2
tri_rallyPointScore = 10
meteorCapturePoints_0 = 3
meteorCapturePoints_1 = 6
meteorCapturePoints_2 = 12
meteorCapturePoints_3 = 24
meteorCapturePoints_4 = 36
meteorCapturePoints_5 = 48
meteorCapturePoints_6 = 60
meteorCapturePoints_7 = 72
meteorCapturePoints_8 = 80
meteorCapturePoints_9 = 100
itemMaxCount_vehicle/quickuse/jump = 4
itemSetCount_vehicle/quickuse/jump = 4
itemMaxCount_vehicle/quickuse/emp = 3
itemSetCount_vehicle/quickuse/emp = 3
itemMaxCount_vehicle/quickuse/boostextender = 3
itemSetCount_vehicle/quickuse/boostextender = 3
EnumerateDownloadableContent: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\RAGE\dlc
    Found DLC: dlc1...and info.txt!
Resource hashSeed = 3
        ...successfully mounted 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\RAGE\dlc/dlc1/info.txt.  ID: 1
    Found DLC: dlc2...and info.txt!
Resource hashSeed = 3
        ...successfully mounted 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\RAGE\dlc/dlc2/info.txt.  ID: 2
idLib::SetProduction( PROD_PRODUCTION )
contentpackage path:  C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/RAGE/dlc/dlc1
contentpackage id:  1
Failed to find DLC at C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/RAGE/dlc/dlc1/base/gameresources.resources
contentpackage path:  C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/RAGE/dlc/dlc2
contentpackage id:  2
Failed to find DLC at C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/RAGE/dlc/dlc2/base/gameresources.resources
couldn't exec rageConfig.cfg
Resetting cheat cvar: aas2_showFloorTrace
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_alignToPointDist
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_minCornerCircleRadius
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_cornerCircleRadius
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_turningCircleAlignmentTolerance
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_pointTolerance
Resetting cheat cvar: atv_bumpForwardScale
Resetting cheat cvar: aa_ZoomSnapScale
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_playerScaleMinimum
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_scaleMinimum
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_ScreenPercentage
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_IconSizeSplitscreen
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_IconSize
Resetting cheat cvar: poi_GoalHeightOffset
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_scale_foot
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_scale_vehicle
Resetting cheat cvar: blendTree_scale
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_jobnav_mindist
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_ant_first_step_foot
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_ant_step_foot
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_ant_first_step
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_minimap_ant_step
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_scopeZoomDistance
Resetting cheat cvar: gc_fictionBlurAmount
Resetting cheat cvar: cine_cameraAccel
Resetting cheat cvar: rcbomb_initialOffset
Resetting cheat cvar: cam_deathCamblurTime
Resetting cheat cvar: cam_deathCamblurAmount
Resetting cheat cvar: revivecam_HeightEnd
Resetting cheat cvar: revivecam_HeightStart
Resetting cheat cvar: spl_qn_pathbonus
Resetting cheat cvar: spl_qn_zpenelty
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_invFadeTime
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_NonPlayerOneShotChance
Resetting cheat cvar: ai_droppedLootDistance
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_ct_jump_dist
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_ct_push_dist
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_ct_push_decayIn
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_ct_push_decayOut
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_ct_checkDist
Resetting cheat cvar: g_playerDamageThreshold
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_combatSubtitleRange
Resetting cheat cvar: swf_subtitleRange
Resetting cheat cvar: vehicle_clientImpactDmg_MaxDmg
Resetting cheat cvar: vehicle_clientImpactDmg_MinDmg
Resetting cheat cvar: vehicle_clientImpactDmg_MaxVel
Resetting cheat cvar: vehicle_clientImpactDmg_MinVel
Resetting cheat cvar: v_steerControlClamp
Resetting cheat cvar: v_steerControlInfluence
Resetting cheat cvar: v_compressiontime
Resetting cheat cvar: v_dusttime
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_clientZoomInDelay
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_clientAuthoritative_warnDist
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_clientAuthoritative_minDistZ
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_clientAuthoritative_Lerp
Resetting cheat cvar: pm_clientAuthoritative_minDist
Resetting cheat cvar: net_voiceVolume
Resetting cheat cvar: net_peer_throttle_bps_decay
Resetting cheat cvar: net_debughud3_bps_max
------- Initializing renderSystem --------
Initializing OpenGL subsystem
...registered window class
...registered fake window class
...using WGL_EXT_swap_control
X..WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear not found
unknown error: 0x0
Rage.exe @ 0x0068f0bc(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x006a96b4(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x006a983c(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x006a98dc(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x0058921e(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x005f9c5b(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec61eba(  ) +  bytes () : WINPROC_wrapper(  )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec624ea(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec64985(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec26fbe(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec2dcb4(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec30152(  ) +  bytes () : SendMessageA(  )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec59600(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
user32.dll @ 0x7ec52851(  ) +  bytes () : CreateWindowExA(  )
Rage.exe @ 0x0058b799(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x0058c05c(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x00565616(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x005ec01f(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
Rage.exe @ 0x006aa4b9(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
ntdll.dll @ 0x7bc806ec(  ) +  bytes () : call_thread_func_wrapper(  )
ntdll.dll @ 0x7bc836bd(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
ntdll.dll @ 0x7bc806ca(  ) +  bytes () : RtlRaiseException(  )
ntdll.dll @ 0x7bc8b48f(  ) +  bytes () : ** UNKNOWN **( ** FUNC_PARAM_ERROR ** )
** MODULE_NAME_ERROR ** @ 0xf75a5295(  ) +  bytes () : start_thread(  )
ERROR: wglCreateContextAttribsARB failed
Dumped console text to C:\users\peter\Saved Games\id Software\Rage\base\ErrorLog_01-08-2017__08-41-46pm.txt.

idRenderSystem::Shutdown()
Shutting down OpenGL subsystem
...releasing DC
...destroying window

***************************
wglCreateContextAttribsARB failed
***************************
```

Comment: You're out of luck: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14675 (Black Ops II doesn't work) and https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13542 (neither RAGE). There are plenty of native games for Linux in Steam. The ones you want are for Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24512&iTestingId=79734

You should be able to get RAGE running, possibly with some workarounds.

BO2 is a different story though.

Whether you either fail or succeed, please make a report on WineAppDB on it, that's how other people know how to run the games and if you make a proper bug report devs are likely to fix it.

Comment: Updated the post.